# Solving Linear equations in python

Tags: python, sympy

Solving a linear equation in python with the use of Sympy

27 (n1 + n2 + n3) = (n1 + n2 + n3)^3

I tried solving, it but I couldn't how to approach this problem. Please let me know, which direction should I follow.

Comment: That equation has no meaningful solution for `n1, n2, n3`. The solution is just `n1 + n2 + n3 == +/- sqrt(27)` so `n1, n2, n3` could be anything.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the comment given by FHTMitchell, this equation has no meaningful solution for n1, n2, n3. You just can have a proportion between these variables as follows:

```
from sympy import *
n1, n2,n3 = symbols('n1, n2, n3')
equation = n1 + n2 + n3
print solve([equation*27, equation*3], (n1, n2,n3))
```

So you'll have:

> {n1: -n2 - n3}